# How do you reference the class within a factory using Factory Girl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I want to reference the class represented by the factory during factory creation. Is that possible?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
factory :foo do # Foo class
  name "Foo"
  ...
  initialize_with { Foo.some_complicated_method(attributes) }

  factory :bar_foo do
    name "Bar"
    initialize_with { BarFoo.some_complicated_method(attributes) }
  end
end
```

What I'd like to do is reference the class name is such a way that I can do this (replacing `__factory_class__` with the appropriate method call):

```
factory :foo do
  name "Foo"
  ...
  initialize_with { __factory_class__.some_complicated_method(attributes) }

  factory :bar_foo do # Runs initialize_with using BarFoo instead of Foo
    name "Bar"
  end
end
```

Is what I'm wanting possible? Note that `BarFoo` is a subclass of `Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. It's described in FactoryGirl's Getting Started docs in [Custom Construction](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction) section:

> When using `initialize_with`, you don't have to declare the class itself when calling `new`; however, any other class methods you want to call will have to be called on the class explicitly.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for the clearing that up.